# ForeignCollection.add() inserts two rows for same object

Tags: ormlite, foreign-collection

I have 3 classes:

A

B which contains an eager ForeignCollection<A> that is constructed with getEmptyForeignCollection()

C which contains an eager ForeignCollection<A> that is constructed with getEmptyForeignCollection()

I create instances of B and C and I INSERT rows into their respective database tables by calling create().  So far, so good.

I create an instance of A and I add it to B's ForeignCollection.  Doing so causes BaseForeignCollection to INSERT a new row in the database table that represents As.  This works as expected (although I would have preferred to do the INSERT manually).

But when I add the same instance of A to C's ForeignCollection, this causes BaseForeignCollection to INSERT another row into the database table that represents As.  This is not desired because A is already there.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?  Is there a way to do what I need to do?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay in responding.

> I create an instance of A and I add it to B's ForeignCollection. Doing so causes BaseForeignCollection to INSERT a new row in the database table that represents As. This works as expected (although I would have preferred to do the INSERT manually).

Right.  You don't have to do it by adding to `B`'s `ForeignCollection` field.  You can just add the `A` class via it's `aDao.create(a)`.  Then when you query for `B`, the foreign-collection will automatically contain it.

> But when I add the same instance of A to C's ForeignCollection, this causes BaseForeignCollection to INSERT another row into the database table that represents As. This is not desired because A is already there.

The `ForeignCollection` is a view into the `A` table.  Once you insert an `A` by any means, it will be in the associated `B` and `C` foreign-collection fields automatically.  If you are using eager fetching, then if you already have your instance of `B` and you create your `A` that has a reference to `B`, you will need to `bDao.refresh(b)` to have the foreign-collection field updated.